# Dateserial return "mismatch in criteria expression error"

Tags: sql, ms-access

Have a table (order ) in access: date1 and date2 both date/time datatype in access

```
date1 | date2
```

I have a simple query in access, runs return the mismatch error:

```
Select date1
FROM order_table 
WHERE DateSerial(Year(date1),Month(Date1)+1,7) > date2
```

It is weird because the datatype does match, have no idea why.

Comment: Use [DateDiff()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DateDiff-Function-E6DD7EE6-3D01-4531-905C-E24FC238F85F) to compare DateTime values: `WHERE DateDiff("d", DateSerial(Year(date1),Month(Date1)+1,7), date2 ) < 0`

Answer (score 2):

`order` is a reserved word in SQL (`ORDER BY`).

You must enclose it in square brackets.

```
Select date1
FROM [order]
WHERE DateSerial(Year(date1),Month(Date1)+1,7) > date2
```

The `DateSerial` WHERE clause worked for me on a test table.

Comment: Thanks, Actually, forget about the order ( I just type a random name), not sure why it return error when I run it.

Comment: Sigh. Please put the *actual* SQL, with actual table and field names, into your question